# How to call a global var document.getElementById into a function to get the .className

Tags: function, global, getelementbyid, var, classname

That's what I use to toggle between the Login and Register divs.

The following is actually working:

```
function myNavLogin()
{
    document.getElementById("Content-Login").className = "Content-On";
    document.getElementById("Content-Register").className = "Content-Off";
}
```

I want to call the next global variable:

```
var divLogin = document.getElementById("Content-Login");
var divRegister = document.getElementById("Content-Register");
```

Inside the function like this way:

```
function myNavLogin()
{
    divLogin.className = "Content-On";
    divRegister.className = "Content-Off";
}
```

The second example isn't working, I think because the variable isn't declared by the correct way or I am calling it bad... please help, thanks.

Regards, Chicler ;)

Comment: Wow this post is really old. I could fix that problem back on day using only css and html, so I think it's time to close the question. Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is probably a simple variable scoping one, but here's a more thorough response anyway.  Global variables are a horrible way to code. You should try to use a more object oriented approach.  You should also consider keeping tag names out of your variable names, since markup is apt to change.  Finally, when toggling classes, it's better to simply add and remove an "on" state and have the "off" state be the default.  Here's an example:

```
var AccountLogic = function(){
  this.elLogin = document.getElementById("Content-Login");
  this.elRegister = document.getElementById("Content-Register");
  this.login = function(){
    this.elLogin.classList.add("content-on");
    this.elRegister.classList.remove("content-on");}
  }
}

var accountLogic = new AccountLogic();
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea is nice but unfortunately it's not working for me :s